# What are some light weight graphics tablet drawers on Ubuntu?

Tags: tablet, wacom

I just got a drawing tablet for drawing diagrams and formulas for my notes. I'm wondering if there are any drawing tools that are friendly for graphics tablet and light weight. Characteristics I'm looking for:

- No mouse required. I can change functionality (draw, erase, draw shapes etc) with easy keyboard shortcuts
- Easy open. I should be able to bring it up with a keyboard shortcut, and it should open instantly in some corner with no loading screen.
- Easy copy. When I'm done I should be able to copy a tight crop of the drawn contents without having to use a separate screen snipping tool.
- Easy close. Closes instantly with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

StylusLabs Write seems like exactly what you are looking for.  http://www.styluslabs.com/download/

Comment: Working nicely. Thank you! Will leave this question open for a bit longer.

Comment: By the way, just wondering: is there a way to copy the contents without a screen snipping tool?